# How to make view always visible on screen within the app?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, view, uiviewcontroller

I need to make a banner view at the bottom of the screen. It should be always on screen. I need to push/present other viewcontroller and it view should be visible.

I made it with container view, but when I push/present other VCs - they show above it.

Is there any way to make it?

Comment: I guess you can make a base view controller and add this view at the bottom of that view controller and then inherit all other view controllers from this base controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use an UIWindow? You can makeKeyAndVisible() to make the UIWindow always be visible on screen

`let view = UIWindow()
 view.center = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100) // This is where your view at
 view.makeKeyAndVisible() // This make your view bring to front`

Answer (score 0):

Add it as a subview of the application window..

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.insertSubview(yourView, at: (UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.subviews.count)!)
```