# .xib file at a higher level, to always keep it visible

Tags: ios, swift, xib

in the first ViewController I load TabbarView.xib (yellow rectangle), when I go to the second ViewController it goes away, how can I keep it always visible in any screen I go to?

I would like it on a higher level, to always keep it visible.

**first ViewController**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var gotoVC: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        gotoVC.addTarget(self, action: #selector(gotoVCAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        
    }
    
    @objc func gotoVCAction() {
        
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoVC2", sender: nil)
        
    }


}
```

**TabbarView.xib**

```
import UIKit

class TabbarView: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        print("TabbarView")
        
    }
    
}
```

I would like it on a higher level, to always keep it visible.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gw7D8.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hziJj.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVGQs.png)

**Update**, after days of research I thought I had found the solution with **windowNew?.windowLevel = .alert**

but now the gotoVC2 button no longer works, because windowNew covers the entire screen, making the button underneath it no longer usable.

**How can I keep usable the buttons at a lower level than WindowNew?**

**Scene Delegate**

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

var windowNew: UIWindow?

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    
    windowNew = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    
    let rootViewController = TabbarView()
    
    windowNew?.windowLevel = .alert
    
    windowNew?.rootViewController = rootViewController
    
    windowNew?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    
}
```

Comment: Easiest way is to use another UIWindow and put it above everything else.

Comment: Hi Larme, Could you give me an example please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45750659/how-to-make-view-always-visible-on-screen-within-the-app ?